# GET REQUEST AND RESPONSE XML IN SOAP ::Lite Request perl

Tags: xml, perl, soap

I am using SOAP::Lite for a service .Now what i want is to save the request and response xml for that a soap request but i am not able to get the xml for request and response .

**SOAP**

```
$soap_object->on_action( sub { $soapAction->{Auth} });

        my $response = $soap_object->Auth(
                                SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('strUserName')->value($user_name),
                                SOAP::Data->type('string')->name('strPassword')->value($password)
                        );
```

For this request i want to  save the request and response .Please suggest where i can get the required XML

Comment: Did my answer stop working? :P

Comment: yes this is not working properly

Comment: did you get any further? do you have a new problem?

Comment: problem is same but i am found best way to track the xml $response->{_context}->{_transport}->{_proxy}->{_http_response}->{_request}->{_content};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of googling reveals that SOAP::Lite's underlying user agent (which is called the [*transport layer*](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/SOAP-Lite/lib/SOAP/Transport.pod)) is LWP::UserAgent. You can [add handlers](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#Handlers) to the user agent that do stuff with the request and response objects when they are sent or received.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->add_handler( request_prepare => sub { my($req, $ua, $h) = @_; say $req->decoded_content; });
$ua->add_handler( response_done => sub { my($res, $ua, $h) = @_; say $res->decoded_content; });

$ua->get('http://www.example.org');
```

This code will output an empty GET request body, and some HTML response.

[SOAP::Lite's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/SOAP::Lite#transport-optional-transport-object) tells us how to get the transport client.

```
my $transport = $soap_object->transport; # or $client
```

Now that thing should be a subclass of LWP::UserAgnt, and you should just be able to set handlers on it. I don't have any SOAP things handy to try this, but I have done it in the past.

Alternatively you could also subclass SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client and add your own stuff to it that dumps every request/response pair as nicely indented XML. You could then use that client as a drop-in replacement.